# How to convert binary data and mime to image in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have no idea how can I convert binary data and mime to image URL

Here is the binary for a valid image with mime=image/jpeg

```
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
```

Comment: `<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64{binary data}" />` should work.

Comment: this is a base64 encoded image. it can be used like this <img alt="image" src="data:image/png;base64,/9j/4QAYRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP/sABFEdWNreQABAAQAAABGAAD/7QAsUGhvdG9zaG9wIDMuMAA4QklNBCUAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" /> . Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 9):

This can be achieved in HTML:

**HTML:**

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{binary data}" />
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/poej7r6k/

Answer (score 3):

If you want to display it, you can just set something like this:

```
$("img").attr("src","data:image/;base64,"+myHexData);
```

Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/kgL62m95/

Comment: This solution worked for me but I need to add jpg after image/

Answer (score 1):

you can not showing large files by using ***`<img sc="" />`***  .it have some restriction include chrome but may work in fire fox .

```
This code work for me 



 var base64 = /*base 64 data*/
            var pdfs = atob(base64);
            var len = pdfs.length;
            var bytes = new Uint8Array(len);
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                bytes[i] = pdfs.charCodeAt(i);
            }
            saveDowloadedData(bytes.buffer,'image');
        function saveDowloadedData(data, filename) {
            var a = document.createElement("a");
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.style = "display: none";
            blob = new Blob([data], { type: "octet/stream" }),
                url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

            a.href = url;
            a.download = filename;
            a.click();
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);

        }
```

in blob type you put "octet/stream" it downloads 
or type of image or file it shows as per the file

Answer (score 1):

Following  pure HTML solution worked for me.

```
const binData = "your binary data"

<img alt="img"  src={'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + window.btoa(binData)} />
```

I needed to use `window.btoa` as I was getting JS `btoa` is deprecated warning.

> This function is only provided for compatibility with legacy web
> platform APIs and should never be used in new code, because they use
> strings to represent binary data and predate the introduction of typed
> arrays in JavaScript. For code running using Node.js APIs, converting
> between base64-encoded strings and binary data should be performed
> using Buffer.from(str, 'base64') andbuf.toString('base64').

There are also buffer based solution as [listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68849233/convert-a-string-to-base64-in-javascript-btoa-and-atob-are-deprecated)