# Convert a string to base64 in JavaScript. btoa and atob are deprecated

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, base64

I have been working on some projects in VS Code lately and suddenly started receiving notifications in my code that btoa and atob are now deprecated.  I can't find any resource for this besides VS Code. If this is true, what alternative is there?

Comment: Those functions are decidedly *not* deprecated. It would help if you provided the exact error you're seeing.

Comment: According to VS Code they are deprecated.   It advises to use Buffer.from(str, "base64") but that does not exist in JavaScript.

Comment: It [definitely does exist in Javscript](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_static_method_buffer_from_array), in Node. [`btoa`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa) is for the web. You question has the `web` tag, so I assumed you were using the web, but your IDE seems to think you're writing Node. So, which is it?

Comment: They are alive an well in the [HTML Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#dom-btoa-dev) (updated today). Is this the same issue: [base64 - How to encode base 64 string in ReactJS when btoa is deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68493486/how-to-encode-base-64-string-in-reactjs-when-btoa-is-deprecated). On [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Base64) is says: "Note that btoa() expects to be passed binary data, and will throw an exception if the given string contains any characters whose UTF-16 representation occupies more than one byte."

Comment: I wrestled a bear once had a good idea. I am writing a Vue project so it probably thinks I am trying to write in node.

Comment: For more context: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/40754

Answer (score 153):

The Node btoa() and atob() functions are the only ones that have been deprecated. However, if you're working on the DOM code (front-end) and see this deprecated notice, you can use the window object to get around it.

```
window.atob()
```

[For more info](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45566)

Answer (score 98):

**TLDR:**
These functions btoa and atob are deprecated for Node JS. If you are coding for the web browser you just need to prepend the window to get rid of this deprecation mark.

to encode :

```
window.btoa('test')
```

result: dGVzdA==

to decode

```
window.atob('dGVzdA==')
```

result: test

---

Otherwise, you could install buffer with "yarn add buffer" or "npm i buffer"  to run on browser. The buffer module's API is identical to node's Buffer API.

Here is a React sample using javascript module to browser, but it can run on any modern javascript frontend app that uses webpack or parcel or even vanilla javascript with script src:

```
//this will run on browser    
import React from "react";
import { Buffer } from 'buffer';
export default function App() {

  const encodeBase64 = (data) => {
    return Buffer.from(data).toString('base64');
  }
  const decodeBase64 = (data) => {
    return Buffer.from(data, 'base64').toString('ascii');
  }

  return <div>
    {'encoded test to base64 = ' + encodeBase64('test')}<br />
    {'decoded dGVzdA== to ascII = ' + decodeBase64('dGVzdA==')}
  </div>;
}
```

The above react hook will result:

```
encoded test to base64 = dGVzdA==
decoded dGVzdA== to ascII = test
```

btoa(): accepts a string where each character represents an 8bit byte. If you pass a string containing characters that cannot be represented in 8 bits, it will probably break. Probably that's why btoa is deprecated.

atob(): returns a string where each character represents an 8-bit byte.

If you are using nodejs just replace atob and btoa with Buffer. [Here is the official documentation Buffers in nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/advanced/buffers/how-to-use-buffers/):

```
//With NodeJS

export const encodeBase64 = (data) => {
    return Buffer.from(data).toString('base64');
}
export const decodeBase64 = (data) => {
    return Buffer.from(data, 'base64').toString('ascii');
}
```

Answer (score 44):

Still within VS Code, I had a look into the comments for the deprecated btoa(str) function. It suggests the following as a replacement:

```
const base64Str = Buffer.from(str, 'utf8').toString('base64');
```

Comment: How about `atob`?

Comment: @AseerKTMiqdad simply do the oposite: `const str = Buffer.from(base64str, 'base64').toString('utf8');`

Comment: The Buffer class is not available in the browser..

Comment: @Peter, for browser apps, you need to install the `Buffer` lib via `npm i buffer` then import it with `import { Buffer } from "buffer";`

Comment: this one worked for me,

    var byteCharacters = Buffer.Buffer.from(base64, 'base64').toString('binary');

Answer (score 30):

`btoa` and `atob` are only deprecated for Node.js. If you prepend the `window.` you will get rid of this deprecation mark.

On the other hand, if you are trying to use `btoa` or `atob` in the back-end side, you definitely should use `Buffer` interface.

References:

1. https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45566#issuecomment-905057883
2. https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45566
3. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/btoa (No deprecation warnings!)