# I am trying to a play a bas64 encoded mp3 using angular and typescript

Tags: html, angular, typescript, html5-audio

I am trying to a play a bas64 encoded mp3 in angular. I have a byteArray that I am then converting to a base64. I do not think that this byte array is corrupt
because when I convert it and place the base64 string on stackblitz `https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-audio-blob-rce4y1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts` The file converts and plays without a problem. In my code below I get an error "*ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window'"*

My Tyepscript method to call my controllder end point to retrieve converted base 64 from byteArray.

```
export class MediaPlayComponent {
@ViewChild('audioTag') audioTag:ElementRef;
audioSource = '';
if(fileExtension == 'mp3')
{
this.testService.getUrl(`fileEndpoint-file/${doc.id}/source`)
    .subscribe((data) => {
        console.log("Data log below");
        console.log(data);
         data ='audio/ogg;base64,' + data; 
         var binary= this.convertDataURIToBinary(data);
         var blob = new Blob([binary], {type : 'audio/mp3'});
         var blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
         this.audioSource = blobUrl;
         console.log("blob below");
         console.log(blobUrl);
         //this.audioTag.nativeElement.setAttribute('src',this.audioSource);
         console.log("Audio" + this.audioSource);

      })
}

 convertDataURIToBinary(dataURI) {
    console.log("URI Below"); 
    console.log(dataURI); 
    var BASE64_MARKER = ';base64,';
    var base64Index = dataURI.toString().indexOf(BASE64_MARKER) + BASE64_MARKER.length;
    var base64 = dataURI.toString().substring(base64Index);
    var raw = window.atob(decodeURIComponent(base64));
    var rawLength = raw.length;
    var array = new Uint8Array(new ArrayBuffer(rawLength));

    for(var i = 0; i < rawLength; i++) {
      array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return array;
}
```

HTML

```
<audio [src]="audioSource | safe:'url'" id="audio"  controls #audioTag></audio>
```

Comment: you probably get some escaped/corrupted data here `this.testService.getUrl(\`fileEndpoint-file/${doc.id}/source\`)`, so it fails..

Answer (score 0):

use the buffer library, as `window.atob` is being deprecated

```js
// import library
import { Buffer } from "buffer";

// define data
const b64 = "SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQ==";
const str = 'Hello, World!'

// define conversion functions
const decode = (str: string):string => Buffer.from(str, 'base64').toString('binary');
const encode = (str: string):string => Buffer.from(str, 'binary').toString('base64');

// use functions
let decodedData = decode(b64);
let encodedData = decode(decodedData);
```

Comment: _window.atob is being deprecated_ - see [Convert a string to base64 in JavaScript. btoa and atob are deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68849233/convert-a-string-to-base64-in-javascript-btoa-and-atob-are-deprecated)